# Use textbox entry in a sentence

Tags: forms, vba, excel

I have specific TextBoxes I input information into and I'd like to use the info from the TextBox to complete a sentence.

Example: Bob had a _____ bike that cost _____. The blanks would be completed with what is filled in those specific TextBoxes. Which would come together on the click of my "copy" button.

I've only gotten this far. I need the other words to stay static and only fill in the blanks.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    If (Value1 = True) Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Copy
        textBox2.Text =  textBox1.Text
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you talking about UserFoms controls or worksheet ones? What is "Value1"? What is to be taken from cell "A1"? Why are you cpying textbox1 contnt into textbox2?

Comment: Yes, I am talking about UserForm controls on a Excel form.

Comment: What is "Value1"? What is to be taken from cell "A1"? Why are you copying textbox1 content into textbox2?

Comment: Yes, I am talking about UserForm controls on a Excel form. Value1 is a radio button. The information taken from cell 1 is inputed manually into a textbox. The code is clearly wrong, as mentioned I'm not very good at this.  But I have radio buttons assigned to specific cells. I have one copy button that copies a specific cell depending on what radio button is selected.  I want to be able to click a specific radio button and when I click the copy button it not only pulls the info from the cell but also pulls info I've inputted into a textbox on form.

Comment: Hope that made sense?

Comment: show your userform and where data are to be read from and written in

Answer (score 0):

Textboxes on a userform can be referenced as a method.

So, if your textboxes are named "Textbox1" and "Textbox2", then you can refer to them with:

```
Me.Textbox1
Me.Textbox2

'Can only be used within the userform code only; to use the names _
    elsewhere, you'll need to save them to a variable
```

You can change the text in a textbox with `.value`

```
Me.Textbox2.Value = Me.Textbox1.Value
```

If you need to use a variable in place of the textbox's name, then you can `.Controls` method:

```
Dim textboxName As String
textboxName = "Textbox1"

Me.Controls(textboxName) = "New value"
```

The contents of a range can be saved into a variable, then passed onto the userform:

```
savedText = ws.Range("A1").Value
Me.Textbox1.Value = savedText
```

Hope this helps!